# How long can I pause before my score won't be uploaded?

Tags: twenty

An update to Twenty introduced leaderboards powered by Google Play. However, the game prevents you from uploading the score if you "paused excessively", as it happened once when I played the game while on the bus and had to pause every few minutes. So, how much pausing can I do before it is considered excessive by the game?